# Install Laravel on ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I am new to `laravel`. I am following [this](http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/) tutorial to install it on `Ubuntu`. I have successfully managed to install all the `PHP` dependencies and `Laravel` is cloned successfully but when I do `chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/app/storage`, I am getting `No such file or Directory`.
I checked it manually and it is not there, I added the directory manually but when I run `artisan` comand to create controller, I am seeing this error
**/var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log**

Comment: It would be useful to have the contents of the log file to understand the issue better.

Comment: Please double check the permission for laravel.log file in logs folder. I too had the same issue I did change the permission of storage folder but laravel.log file's permission didn't change..

Comment: `/var/www/html/laravel/app/storage`

Answer (score 4):

You might need to update composer before you can fire up artisan.
Please try with following command:

```
composer.phar update
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of laravel are you using? Later versions of Laravel don't have the storage folder inside "app" but in the project root.

Try with:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/storage
```

However, I would recommend that you use 755 instead of 777. Using 777 is almost always bad practice.

In cases where you need more permissions, you could try changing the user owner / group owner of the folder, with the following code:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup laravel/somefolder
```